# How to change quad transparency in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a kind of space-shooter game which has a simplistic geometric style. I got a scrolling background and put it in as a quad. The scrolling background works, but I thought it was a little to bright so I wanted to change the opacity when I realized. "Oh wow, I'm a stupid brain new developer, and I don't know anything about quads or 3D repeating textures and how they behave in a 2D game, since all I've been doing is following a tutorial on how to implement a scrolling background." So I just need some simple code that will change the transparency of my quad.

Answer (score 1):

First step you should change the material **rendering mode** "the material which assigned to quad or any 3d model " change it to ***Fade*** or ***transparent*** 
[image]  
 
 
Now You Can change the opacity of the **color** on material this will be applied 
[image]   
 
 
Second Step change color from code just you need a reference for MeshRenderer Component

```
 public MeshRenderer quad; // quad to change its opacity 

 public void setOpacity(float opacity)
 {
    Color oldColor =  quad.sharedMaterial.color; // old color 
    // now will set old color but with new opacity 
    quad.sharedMaterial.color = new Color(oldColor.r,oldColor.g,oldColor.g,opacity);
 }
```

what is occurs here? Color Component use rgba coloring system 
r for red value , g for green , b for blue , a  for alpha value 
 
all from 0 to 1 so when you set alpha value = 1; this means color is non transparent 
 
when you set alpha value = 1; this means color is  completely transparent 
0